# Given square matrices A and B, how to solve T obeys Transpose[T]. A . T = B?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra, nonlinear

Dear Mathematica experts,

Given two square matrices, A and B, how do we use Mathematica to solve a matrix T such that T satisfies this matrix equation? (Here we have A,B,T $\in$ general linear matrix GL($N,\mathbb{Z}$) with integer coefficient.)

```
Transpose[T]. A . T = B
```

Roughly we want to solve T by given A and B by some Mathematica command line:

```
Solve[Transpose[T]. A . T == B, T]
```

But this won't work.

Conditions:

- 1. We can focus on A and B are **symmetric integer matrices**, but A and B are **not necessarily diagonal**. $A_{ij}=A_{ji}, B_{ij}=B_{ji} \in \mathbb{Z}$.
- 2. T is an **integer matrix** but may not be symmetric. $T_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z}$.
- 3. All of matrices, including the given A and B, and the solution T have **determinant det $= \pm 1$**. Namely, $\det A = \det B = \det T =\pm 1$ (either 1 or $-1$). This shall be called **unimodular**.

(p.s. Ideally it is good to impose T is not only general linear matrix GL($N,\mathbb{Z}$) but special linear matrix SL($N,\mathbb{Z}$) such that the determinant det(T) =1 is better.)

As a test example, let us try two rank-10 matrices which indeed have solutions satisfy the above 3 conditions:

> A = ({ {2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
> {-1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
> {0, -1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0},
> {0, 0, -1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
> {0, 0, 0, -1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
> {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0},
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 2, 0, 0, 0},
> {0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0},
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1}    });
>
> B = ({
> {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
> {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
> {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
> {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1}    });

How do we solve T? that satisfies Transpose[T]. A . T = B? Please give a rank-10 T matrix so we can compare.

I saw related questions, but none of them give a complete answer:

[Matrix equivalence over the integers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183464/95437)

[Finding an Integer, Unimodular Matrix that connects two given matrices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115902/95437)

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115905/95437

This answer uses Smith normal form to solve:  T'. A . T = B but not Transpose[T]. A . T = B because T' $\neq$ Transpose[T] in general.

Edit: Nasser asked a smaller rank test example, here:

- A = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}. B= {{0,1},{1,2}}.

Ans: T={{1, 1},{0, 1}}.

- A = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}. B = {{2,5},{5,12}}.

Ans: T= {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}

(These T are in both GL($2,\mathbb{Z}$) and also SL($2,\mathbb{Z}$))

Thanks a lot!
Zeta

---

### EDIT to response to who absent-minded closing my question and falsely claiming the response to [How to solve for $\mathbf{X}$ in a matrix equation $\mathbf{X A} \mathbf{X}^\top = \mathbf{B}$?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/251537/95437) solve my question.

1. I require that all A, B, T are integer matrices. The approach that given in the cited answer there does not produce integer matrix T.
2. Here I require symmetric integer A and symmetric integer B, and possibly generic non-symmetric integer T. (There is no diagonal matrix as the cited question.)
3. In fact I require UNIMODULAR determinant = 1 for A, B, T matrices in all my examples.
4. For those who closed this question, please use my toy rank-10 example to give me a Mathematica solution to it. Just to test that your answer really solves this.

Comment: If I understand the question well, then it is a possible dupe of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251537/how-to-solve-for-mathbfx-in-a-matrix-equation-mathbfx-a-mathbfx-top  in which case, there's also an analytic solution (see the accepted answer)

Comment: Thanks @Hans Olo, we can assume that A and B are symmetric integer matrices, but not diagonal. So, this one does not solve my question:  NO [How to solve for  in a matrix equation ⊤=] https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251537/ DOES NOT solve my question

Comment: In the link the matrices are not assumed to be diagonal, see the example. Then, if I understand correctly the analytical solution (and assorted Mathematica code) should answer your question

Comment: This might be of interest https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GramianReduce/

Comment: I don't know who closed this question -- but that approach does NOT work! That is ridiculous!

Comment: I suggest you ask about this on Mathematics Stack Exchange - once you know how to solve it then we should be able to put together the code, as Mathematica has ample built-in primitives to build an algorithm from like LatticeReduce and Orthogonalize, resource functions etc.

Comment: @flinty, I add question here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4824296/1186216 many thanks!!

Comment: [discussion  moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150260/discussion-on-question-by-zeta-given-square-matrices-a-and-b-how-to-solve-t-obe)

Comment: @zeta Solve works. You just didn't follow the required structure. `A = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
 B = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}}; n = 2; T = Table[t[i, j], {i, n}, {j, n}]; sol = Solve[Transpose[T] . A . T == B, Flatten[T], Integers]; Do[Print[{{t[1, 1], t[1, 2]}, {t[2, 1], t[2, 2]}} /. sol[[i]] // MatrixForm], {i, Length[sol]}]`.

Comment: @JimB you shall try the larger size matrix not just rank-2, please try the rank-10 case

Comment: Understood.  My comment is that you had the command incorrectly written for any size matrix.  And I would try a larger size but you haven't described how you generate $A$ and $B$.  Also, at least for a 2x2 set of matrices there can be multiple solutions.

Comment: Notice however that the entry coefficient of T$_{ij} \not\in \mathbb{Z}$ in Hans Olo answer, hence this does not satisfy the criterion given in the OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using the A, B matrices provided by the OP in the question we use the solution found in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/251551/61267) and we find

```
T=B.MatrixPower[Inverse[B].Inverse[A], 1/2] // N // Chop
(* {{1.09147, 0.830786, 0.971318, 0.729422, 0.525503, 0.341544, 0.168366, 0.470968, 0, 0}, {0.830786, 2.06279, 2.03118, 1.49682, 1.07097, 0.693868, 0.341544, 0.971318, 0, 0}, {0.971318, 2.03118, 3.55961,2.37272, 1.66519, 1.07097, 0.525503, 1.56021, 0, 0}, {0.729422, 1.49682, 2.37272, 2.58829, 1.56021, 0.971318, 0.470968, 1.13968, 0, 0}, {0.525503, 1.07097, 1.66519, 1.56021, 1.89443, 0.96021,      0.445816, 0.812512, 0, 0}, {0.341544, 0.693868, 1.07097, 0.971318, 0.96021, 1.36892, 0.489242, 0.525503, 0, 0}, {0.168366, 0.341544, 0.525503, 0.470968, 0.445816, 0.489242, 0.923108, 0.258454, 0, 0}, {0.470968, 0.971318, 1.56021, 1.13968, 0.812512, 0.525503, 0.258454, 1.44861, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.}} *)
```

And as expected the solution satisfies the original equation:

```
Transpose[T].A.T - B // Chop
(* {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Comment: $T_{ij}\notin \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The solution is in general not unique.

Comment: Indeed I need to impose T is an integer matrix. I know integer T exists.

Comment: But thanks for the answer, I voted up for your effort.

Comment: I should not vote up - this causes the confusion - and also this falsefully close my question...

Comment: This answer does not solve the original problem (OP) because the T matrix is not integer coefficient matrix. We need integer T matrix.

Comment: Even though this answer is not what OP was looking for, it may help others who _are_ looking for real solutions, and it can be made a lot faster by doing `X = B . MatrixPower[Inverse[N@B] . Inverse[N@A], 1/2]` converting to numerical inside instead of at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you're asking the impossible.

Here is an example for 3x3 matrices $A$ and $B$.  There are 48 integer-only solutions.  Would not having 10x10 matrices result in many, many more integer-only solutions?

```
A = {{5, 0, -2}, {0, 1, 0}, {-2, 0, 1}};
B = A;
T = Table[t[i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
sol = Solve[Transpose[T] . A . T == B, Variables[T], Integers];
(T /. # // MatrixForm) & /@ sol
```

[image: 48 solutions for a specific 3x3 matrix]

```
(Det[T] /. # // MatrixForm) & /@ sol
```

[image: Determinant values]

```
Transpose[#] . A . # - B & /@ (T /. # & /@ sol)
{{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,  0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}
```

If you could present code to generate matrices $A$ and $B$ for any size, that would help tell if for 10x10 matrices there might be too many solutions to determine.

Comment: I think they just want _any_ solution for $T$ by some _clever_ method that leans on the structure of the problem, or linear algebra magic, rather than brute force ... which I agree will be impossible for 10x10 as you mentioned. I don't think that magic exists yet, and this looks like an open problem.

Comment: @flinty I hope that is true.  But the OP needs to state that.  I answered because I was bothered that a relatively new *Mathematica* user stated "This won't work" when at least for smaller matrices they simply had coding errors.

Comment: A solution can be obtained with `obj = (Transpose[T] . A . T - B // Flatten )^2  // Total ; var = Variables[T] ; con  = Element[#, Integers] & /@ var ;  NMinimize[{obj, con}, var] // Last`.

Comment: @I.M. That works (at least for smaller matrices).  You should write that up as an answer.  (Theoretically it should work for any size of matrix.  But it might take a long, long time for larger matrices.)

Comment: @I.M. or alternatively `obj[X_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Total[Abs[Transpose[X] . A . X - B], 2];` and then this avoids the Last/Rule stuff: `T0 = NArgMin[obj[X], X ∈ Matrices[{10, 10}, Integers]]` But it will never terminate with a correct matrix for a 10x10 on my machine. The search space is too big.

Comment: Thanks, are you able to run the 10x10 matrix output some of the valid result? that will be the correct answer if you get any.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I was able to do some 3x3 matrices by was too impatient to see if 4x4 matrices would finish.  I suspect my computer isn't powerful enough to do 10x10.  I'm guessing (but I really don't know) that there are zillions of solutions for a 10.x10 matrix so I'm wondering as @flinty has commented, "Do you need a single or a few solutions or do you need all solutions?"